# Passing parameters between pages issue with multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have an web forms app that recently started experiencing issues. App is deployed on the SharePoint. We have multiple users entering data into the scheduler.

Each user has access to different facility and I have been passing the facility number to the user using `HttpRuntime.Cache["FacN"]` value.

On the scheduler form I filter **LinqToSql** connection by setting the hidden field to that cached value. And scheduler is supposed to display data for that facility only.

It was working fine until we got few users entering data in the same time (in  IE, SharePoint server). If 2 users entering data at the same time - then they would see the events from the different facility.

I also tried using `HttpContext.Current.Session["FacN"]` - but in that case it didn't retain the value of the facility. Please advise how else I can pass the facility parameter?

Comment: Cache is shared between all users, that's pretty much its purpose. Session is specific to each user but then you need to make sure you actually identify users so that they get back their session on the next operation. Read up on how session works and what you need to do to get it working.

Comment: Thank you.  We are using SharePoint and neither cookies or session is working. I am not sure what else to try. I had switched it to use querystring, but need to find a way to pass parameter back to the default page without use of querystring.

Comment: I think session state is the correct approach to use, so I suggest trying to figure out why exactly it doesn't work for you. Reading the docs starting at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648090.aspx might give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timestamp variable with FacN.

1. First user and second user get the FacN with timestamp at the same time.
2. First user update the FacN, timestamp  will be changed.
3. Second user want to update the FacN, need to compare timestamp, if different will be return update failure.